loading env variable from file in makefile
Given an .env file with a variable DB_USER=foo@bar, for a Makefile:
.ONESHELL:

SHELL:=/bin/bash

all:
    set -o allexport;source .env ;set +o allexport && echo $(DB_USER)

and
$ make all
$ set -o allexport;source .env ;set +o allexport && echo 


testing this in terminal works:
$ set -o allexport;source .env ;set +o allexport; && echo $DB_USER
$ foo@bar

how to fix this in the makefile?

@G.M. oh I see, please how to make this work within make?

Change echo $(DB_USER) to echo $$DB_USER.
Then:
$ cat Makefile 
.ONESHELL:

SHELL:=/bin/bash

all:
    set -o allexport;source .env ;set +o allexport && echo $$DB_USER
    
$ cat .env
DB_USER=Me

$ make
set -o allexport;source .env ;set +o allexport && echo $DB_USER
Me

Why?
The recipe is running in a shell whose parent is make. $(DB_USER) refers to a make-variable
which is undefined in make's environment. $DB_USER is a reference to a variable
in the environment of the child shell, which you have set in the .env file in
that same shell, so you can potentially reference it. A child process can't push environment
variables up into its parent, and even if could, it's pointless: it's only the
running shell that needs the value.
You need to escape $DB_USER as $$DB_USER in the context of the recipe,
otherwise make will expand $DB_USER = $(D)B_USER = B_USER before the recipe
is even run. GNU Make manual: 6.1 Basics of Variable References

A dollar sign followed by a character other than a dollar sign, open-parenthesis
or open-brace treats that single character as the variable name. Thus, you could
reference the variable x with ‘$x’. However, this practice can lead to confusion...

Likewise you always need to escape $shellvar as $$shellvar in recipe context.
